# How to calculate CPU utilization for an operating system?

Tags: operating-system

Suppose we have a multi-programmed computer where each job has identical characteristics: Each job runs N computational periods of length T, where half of that time is spent on I/O and half on computation. Jobs are dispatched in a simple round-robin manner and I/O activity can overlap with CPU operations. Compute the average turnaround time (average total time to complete each job), throughput (average number of jobs completed per time period T), and processor utilization (percentage of time that the processor is not idle) for the cases of one, two, and four simultaneous jobs for the following two cases: 
(a) each period T is distributed as follows: CPU – first half; I/O – second half 
(b) CPU – during the first and the third quarter; I/O – during the other quarters.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on Linux `perf` seems to be the perfect choice to you. You trace all syscall with

```
perf star -e `syscall:_your_syscall_`
```

You can attach to a process by its pod, but make sure it is compiled with debug symbols enabled. Mainstream hardware events are available in perf with `-d` option.

```
perf stat -d ./bin
```

For more info take a look at www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Comment: I'm studying Operating Systems and I read that question and I couldn't answer it.
That is not the answer I'm looking for but thank you anyway.
here is the answer to that question (I don't understand it)
[the question and answer](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~kifer/Courses/cse306/homeworks/hw1.pdf)
question number 2